# Convert datetime Persian

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time, persian-calendar

I am trying to convert persian datetime to standard datetime
This is my code:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar());
```

But I get this error for some date:

> Day must be between 1 and 29 for month12

Any one can help me?

Comment: There are a *lot* of identical SO questions. Have you checked them? The answer is that `DateTime` is inherently Gregorian and doesn't have an associated calendar anyway. The calendar can be used for conversions but doesn't change the behavior of `DateTime`. The [constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,229) only uses the Calendar to calculate the Ticks value, it's not stored itself

Comment: Is the error thrown by `Convert.ToDateTime`? That method is essentially the same and no better than `DateTime.Parse`. If you use it without an explicit CultureInfo parameter it will parse the string using the current user's locale settings. What's the string that causes the error?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre], with a valid Persian datetime as input, and an expected datetime as output?

Comment: What is the value of `textBox1.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: The textbox should be a Persian date.  Month 12 in Persian can only be from 1 to 29 and your value is outside the range.  If textbox is Persian than Convert.ToDateTime() will not work.

Comment: As far as I can see, https://date-today.com/en/shamsi-calendar-1402.html - the last month Pisces - contains **29 days only**. Note that the calendar starts on `March` and ends on `February`

Answer (score 1):

You can use four way to convert persian datetime to standard datetime

1.

```
string text = "1394/05/21";
DateTime dt= DateTime.Parse(text, new CultureInfo("fa-IR"));
```

2. 

```
string text = "1394/05/21";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(text, new CultureInfo("fa-IR"))
```

3. 

```
string text = "1394/05/21";
int Year = int.Parse(text.Split("/")[0]);
int Month = int.Parse(text.Split("/")[1]);
int Day = int.Parse(text.Split("/")[2]);

DateTime dt = new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar());
```

4. 

```
string text = "1394/05/21";
int Year = int.Parse(text.Split("/")[0]);
int Month = int.Parse(text.Split("/")[1]);
int Day = int.Parse(text.Split("/")[2]);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar());
```

Comment: Thank you but with this codes we have the same problem.

Comment: @Fatemeh,I tested this code and it was ok. Please send your  example data and code samples so we can check, You can see Result : dotnetfiddle.net/CJ0wMO